# rxbag export crashes

Tags: ros, rosbag, bagfile, rxbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to export data from a bagfile using rxbag. After plotting without problems the data I'm interested on I do right click-> export to csv and after naming the file everything crashes with just a seg fault:

1- Does anybody know why does this happen and how to solve this?

2- Has somebody any C++ code or python using the rosbag API to extract data from a bagfile and save it to a csv to use it as a template?

Any help will be appreciated! :)

I'm on Ubunutu 11.10 and rxbag crashes both in Ros electric and fuerte :S

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47661/rxbag-export-crashes./) by [Jep](https://answers.ros.org/users/2367/jep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2012-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After some checks, I can contribute that:

1- In another machine with Ubuntu 12.04 Rxbag was exporting without problems

2- In my machine I end up using:

```
rostopic echo /topic -b=path/to/bagfile.bag -p > output_data.csv
```

That was much faster to use for my purposes than rxbag.

---

Originally posted by [Jep](https://answers.ros.org/users/2367/jep/) with karma: 195 on 2012-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0